# Crystal Reports Vertical Stripes rendered when using DNS name IE10

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, internet-explorer-10

I'm experiencing the following problem on CR 13.0.4 (64 Bit production).

Users use a DNS entry to access our application, e.g.
`http://WebApp:80`             (which then uses `http://123Server:80`)

The errors occurs when vertical stripes are rendered.
[image]

However, when using the server name + port to access the application

```
http://123Server:80
```

Then the report displays perfectly on IE10.

Integrated security is set to False.

In IE9, the reports work fine on both `http://WebApp:80`  and `http://123Server:80`

I've gone through all the Wiki documentation for each release after 13.0.4,
and have found on Release 13.0.7:

ADAPT01665016  Report viewer in webproject deployed on IE10 will display as white dots in browser   KBA1810173

The KBA1810173 mentions white dots, and not stripes.

Does anyone know whether any fixes were done regarding IE10 and DNS Entries?
 Is Crystal even aware of this issue? (Is this a newly reported one that will only be looked at in e.g. SP12 onwards?)

We can't tell the users to set compatibility mode - its the responsibility of the developers to get this working in this case.

Comment: Did you use Default website on IIS? Have you set particula bindings on IIS? In IE debug window have you got some 404 or bobj error?

Comment: I checked now: No bindings in IIS,  no errors on IE debug window, it does not work on either default or non-default site on IIS. It works well in IE11 though. this is IE10 only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE

Look at [Crystal Reports Forum](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3233406) and [SAP Note](http://search.sap.com/ui/notes?id=0001877191&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031383737313931&ssocompatible): this was a bug Release 4, that was developed on IE 9 (not 10 or 11).

This bug was not solved with SP5, SP6, and so on, but there's an easy workaround: put in hour HTML header this tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9,chrome=1" />
```

that forces compatibility mode to IE 9 for IE 10.

---

I can suggest 2 things:

1) Give them a chance... Update to latest versione CR 13.0.11 you can get it  [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

2) I found some unexpected behaviour on IE10 IE11 until I installed 4.5 framework. Is it already installed?

And, if you can, send us a public link to see this problem.

Comment: OK I downloaded SP 10 from the page, (SP 11 was removed by SAP), and the same error occurs. I can confirm that Framework 4.5 has been installed. Its an intranet link unfortunately, but I can send more screenshots... It also works perfectly on IE11 - its only IE10 giving this issue

Comment: Will try now thanks, they said on that link it'll be fixed in SP7 , but definitely not fixed even in SP10. I'm able to replicate it on 3 different servers. In IE10, it works if I dont use a DNS name

Comment: Thanks Emanuele, it does work. It seems like SAP partially missed this though - it seems in some cases then the SP10 alone does not fix the bug up. Thanks again!